# Subjonctif présent et subjonctif passé

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer quelle est la différence entre ces deux phrases ?

> 1)  J’étais surpris qu’elle ne prenne pas ses médicaments.
>
> 2) J’étais surpris qu’elle n’ait pas pris ses médicaments.

Est-ce que la première veut dire qu'elle ne prend toujours pas ses médicaments et la deuxième qu'elle n'a pas pris ses médicaments une fois ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans la première phrase, elle n'a pas pris ses médicaments et ça a surpris la personne à ce moment là (il l'a donc probablement vue ne pas prendre ses médicaments). Une autre interprétation est qu'il était surpris du fait qu'elle ne prenait pas ses médicaments en général.

Dans la deuxième, elle n'avait pas pris ses médicaments, il en a été ensuite informé et a alors été surpris (il a probablement vu la conséquence de l'absence de prise de médicaments).

Answer (score 1):

Dans le premier cas, il s'agit d'un présent du subjonctif qui marque l'habitude ; elle ne prend pas ses médicaments depuis un certain temps déjà et possiblement elle continue à ne pas les prendre si rien n'a été fait dans le sens de les lui faire prendre. Cela signifie que les médicaments ne sont pas pris depuis au moins un jour ou deux bien que s'il s'agit de doses à prendre matin, midi et soir il est possible que ce soit depuis quelques heures.

Dans le second, il peut s'agir de deux possibilités ; soit elle n'a pas pris ses médicament un jour donné à une heure donné  alors qu'une dose avait été prescrite pour ce jour et heure, soit elle ne les a pas pris pendant plusieurs jours.