# Le subjonctif présent vs. le subjonctif passé

Tags: subjonctif

Finissez-le avant qu'il n'arrive.
Finissez-le avant qu'il ne soit revenu.

Pourquoi peut-on utiliser le subjonctif passé s'il s'agit de l'avenir?
Je ne le comprends pas.

Comment: Le subjonctif passé ne sert pas à exprimer une action passée. Le subjonctif est un mode qui permet de parler d'actions dont on n'est pas certain de la réalisation. Dans une proposition subordonnée (c'est le cas dans tes exemples) il sert à exprimer une action qui devra être accomplie avant une autre, les deux étant situées dans le futur. Dans ton exemple il sert donc à indiquer que le fait de finir doit être terminé avant le fait de revenir (d'arriver). Voir [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/90/358) qui explique pourquoi on utilise le subjonctif après *avant que.

Comment: @None Mon papy est mort avant que je naisse/ sois né.
Et dans cette phrase-ci?

Comment: On utilise **toujours** le subjonctif après *avant que*. La différence entre l'emploi du subjonctif présent et du subjonctif passé est dans l'accompli. Dans le contexte de cette phrase la différence est minime, le présent c'est la naissance vue dans son ensemble, il peut être mort pendant l'accouchement ; le passé indique que le fait de naître est terminé, donc la mère a déjà accouché. Dans d'autres cas ([ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34065/358) par exemple) la différence peut être plus grande.